# Language special characters in vue.js template badly encoded

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just started to learn Vue.js and already have a problem. Special characters are badly encoded in templates.

```
<template>
    <div class="navbar">
        <span>VOD</span>

        <ul class="menu">
            <li v-if="user">Konto</li>
            <li v-if="!user">Zaloguj się</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

It's displayed like this: Zaloguj si�. In built js it looks like this: Zaloguj siďż˝. Same thing with text in variables. Is this normal behaviour for Vue.js?

Comment: Make sure your page and your browser all uses the proper encoding to handle the characters you want to display.

Comment: What is used to display the character when it is improperly displayed and version Chrome, Safari, something else?

Comment: Your source file (where `Zaloguj siďż˝` is) is not UTF-8. It probably is some ISO-8859 encoding.

Comment: What IDE are you using and what encoding is your IDE saving your files as?

Comment: Netbeans, UTF8 wo BOM.

Answer (score 4):

Include this in your `<head>` tag inside your `index.html` file:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Of course I have this in index head, It's generated by vue-cli like that.

Comment: It's badly encoded in builded files, not in the source.

Comment: @wortigern Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was the bad encoding of the template file (Home.vue) that VS2019 created automatically. When I saved it as UTF-8 the special characters were displayed just fine.